# Trouble connecting to WiFi network with wifi_iot on Android 12/Pixel 6

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to use the wifi_iot flutter plugin, I have posted this issue on their github and the developer does not seem to know the problem.

The problem is with my Pixel 6 which is running Android 12, I have to manually disconnect from my current WiFi network in order for my app (that is using this plugin) to successfully connect to the specified network.

The plugin works perfectly on my iOS iPad/iPhone and Android 11 tablet

I have been reading on flutter plugin development, I am considering making my own plugin if that will resolve the issue, but I do not know what the problem is. Does anyone know if there were major changes to connecting to WiFi networks from android 11 to 12?

GitHub of wifi_iot plugin:
https://github.com/flutternetwork/WiFiFlutter

Answer (score 1):

Android 12 introduces Wi-Fi STA/STA concurrency, which allows devices to connect to two Wi-Fi networks concurrently.

https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency

User-initiated network switches use the legacy break-before-make flow, where the previous network is fully disconnected before the new network is connected